# functional testing a JMS message queue with JMeter

Tags: jms, jmeter

I've got a REST service that in response to a request, posts a message on a JMS queue. All of the main http functional testing is done using JMeter, so I was wondering if anyone has successfully pulled a JMS message off an existing queue in JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter will do no such thing, but a class that you write to extend MessageListener, register with the queue, and have JMeter instantiate in a JUnit test certainly can.  I'd recommend that you keep the consuming and testing separate.  Write that MessageListener, get it working, and then figure out how to wire it into JMeter.